# Error: CImageHelper::Init () Failed Load of symbol file with path

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017

Using SQL server 2017 (14.0.3029.16) with Always On High Availability environment.

Getting error:

> CImageHelper::Init () Failed load of symbol file with path = C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14..... Error Code 0xc0000004

There is nothing before or after this error and all I have to go by is a SPID. there is no set time, its happened once at 12:30AM and another time at 10:1 5AM.

I did some googling and there was one recommendation of reducing the MAXSIZE of the server memory. We have it set to 433,600 with 500,000 available.

How can I solve the problem and get rid of this error?

**Additional information**

- Total RAM on the server is 500GB
- Forced encryption is not enabled

**Responses to comments**

- > Anything in windows event log - app or system? Any mini dumps generated?

  Event viewer has nothing that correlates with those time frames but something I will have to review further because I do see some errors.
- > For mini dumps - just check `select * from sys.dm_server_memory_dumps`

  Nothing came back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84206/discussion-between-kin-and-tomasz).

Comment: might be too early to tell, but i reduced my "Server Memory Options" down to 90% of whats available and knock on wood, the errors stopped. So in the above i said i had 433,600 being used but it was actually 483,600, brought it down to  453,600. didn't have to restart sql because the total used was only 400,000.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by navigating to

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn
```

on the SQL Server and modifying two `.ini` files within the `Binn` folder. The first is `sqlctr` and the second is `sqlagtctr`.

Upon opening the files you will see that both contain

```
symbolfile=[SYMBOLINSTALLPATH]\sqlagtctr.h
```

or

```
symbolfile=[SYMBOLINSTALLPATH]\qlctr.h
```

nested under `[info]`.

By replacing `[SYMBOLINSTALLPATH]` with the fully qualified path of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn` and restarting the SQL service, I was able to get the issue resolved.

For example, the beginning file content should now look similar to the following:

```
[info]
drivername=[DRIVERNAME]
symbolfile=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlagtctr.h
```